# Converter affects routine auto generated code

Tags: java, jooq

I am using custom type converters with JOOQ, which work fine for tables but create uncompilable code for routines.

For example I have a `public class DateConverter implements Converter<Date, LocalDate>` but when auto-generating code some functions that accept a `date` as a parameter lead to the following code being generated:

```
public static final org.jooq.Parameter<java.time.LocalDate> VALUE_DATE = createParameter("value_date", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.DATE);
```

I understand that [a related feature is planned for 3.5.0 that will probably solve the issue](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2155) but I am on 3.4.4 and wonder if there is a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments, I take that you're looking for a way to prevent jOOQ's code generator from erroneously applying converted data types to stored function parameters.

One workaround I can think of doing this right now is to ensure that none of the procedures / functions is accidentally matched [in the code generator configuration](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-types/). The `<expression/>` only matches either the fully qualified object name (e.g. the parameter) or the unqualified object name.

Another workaround would be to have two distinct code generation configurations: One for tables, the other for routines. That way, it would be much easier to configure converters...

Comment: So no way to tell jooq to ignore the converters when creating the routines?

Comment: Aha, "ignoring" would qualify as a workaround? Well, you could exclude those procedures from the regular expressions used in your `<forcedTypes/>` configuration...

Comment: That would work for me but a simple `((?!FUNCTION).)*` doesn't work - I suppose expression matches on the variable name itself so it will be difficult to differentiate between column names and function parameters based on name only.

Comment: @assylias: No, you can't match the PL/SQL (pgplsql, etc.) text, only the object name is matched by that configuration. People often have very distinct naming schemes, which can be used for these things, but if you don't have that, then the current feature set is really not so useful...

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, is there an easy way to exclude either tables or routines or does it have to be by name?

Comment: Not yet, but I guess we should think about your use-case, [when we implement #3482](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3482)